# Организация очереди сообщений между родителем и сыном

Tags: linux, c, unix, ipc

Нужно организовать передачу числа между родителем и сыном. Код:

```
int
main(void)
{
    int size = sizeof(struct message) - sizeof(long);
    struct message msg;
    int qid = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    msg.mtype = 0;
    msg.value = 2;
    msgsnd(qid, &msg, size, 0);
    if (!fork()) {
        msgrcv(qid, &msg, size, 0, 0);
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

Дочерний процесс намертво зависает на msgrcv. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: я точно не уверен, но может быть сначала сделать msgrcv, а потом уже отправлять.

Comment: Он не намертво зависает, а ждёт, пока оттуда что-нибудь придёт. А оттуда ничего не придёт, потому что msgsnd возвращает EINVAL. А возвращает он его потому, что маны явно говорят нам, что message type must be > 0

Comment: И да, раз уж создаёте с IPC_PRIVATE, то не забывайте удалять при выходе, а то у вас сейчас наверняка ipcs -a уже тысичи ихъ показывает.

Comment: добавлю, что, если это не учебное задание, то очереди скорей всего не тот примитив, которым стоит пользоваться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я как-то использовал в реальном комплексе АСУТП. Довольно неплохо: малые задержки, малый джиттер, гарантированная доставка, простой API, присутствует везде, то есть не требует сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, если честно, то я просто один раз по негратмотности и молодости пытался ими воспользоваться чтобы посылать команды демону вместо простого сокета =))... с тех пор к ним с большим подозрением отношусь (да я знаю, что это всего лишь мои комплексы)... а для задач реального времени наверное действительно будет неплохим выбором...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну, у меня оно тоже было по молодости и неграмотности, и сейчас не помню, почему не unix domain sockets. Выбор шёл между сидением на семафоре с последующим чтением shm и пересылкой сообщений. Оказалось гораздо проще не терять замеры, если идти по второму варианту, проверяли на измерениях с интервалом порядка сотен микросекунд, а это было с хорошим запасом для тех задач. Сейчас я бы сначала посмотрел на ZeroMQ, особенно, если бы не исключался переход к распределённой обработке.